# FasterCSV: several separators

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

My Rails3 app parses user-uploaded CSV files.
As can be expected, users upload tab-separated AND comma-separated files.
I want to support both.

My code:

```
input = CSV.read(uploaded_io.tempfile, { encoding: "UTF-8", :col_sep => "\t"})
```

**QUESTION:**How to change it to support commas too?

FasterCSV's doc describes col_sep as `The String placed between each field.` so `:col_sep => ",\t"` won't work.

Note: All data inside are integers or identifiers, so the probability of someone using `\t` or `,` within the content (not a delimiter) is zero. So usage of the two different delimiters in the same file is not something I expressly want to prevent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

One simple way to do it is to let the user select with a drop-down which  separator they use in their CSV file, and then you just set that value in the `CSV.read()` call.  But I guess you want it automatic. :-)

**Solution 2:**

You can read-in the first line of the CSV file with regular `File.read()` and analyze it by matching the first line against `/,/` and then against `/\t/` ... depending on which RegExp matches, you select the separator in the `CSV.read()` call to the according (single) separator. Then you read in the file with `CSV.read(..., :col_sep => single_separator )` accordingly.

**But Beware:**

At first it looks nice and elegant to want to use `",\t"` as the separator in the method call to allow both -- but please note this would introduce a possible nasty bug!

If a CVS file would contain both tabs and commas by accident or by chance ... what do you do then? 
Separate on both? How can you be sure?  I think that would be a mistake, because CSV separators don't appear "mixed" like this in regular CSV files -- it's always either `','` or `"\t"`

So I think you should not use `",\t"` -- that could be causing huge problems, and that's probably the reason why they did not implement / allow  the `col_sep` option to accept a RegExp.

Comment: See the note I added: the problems you mention are understandable but do not apply here.

Comment: OK, understood.. that means that Solution 2 should work nicely.. correct? :)

Comment: +1 Yes, that's a valid solution, thanks! Before accepting I will wait a day or so, maybe someone knows a forgotten FasterCSV option that does this even more elegantly :-)

Comment: thank you! Looking at the FasterCSV API #new call, it doesn't look like it :)  http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html#M000021

Answer (score 0):

If the data does not contain escaping quotes and such, just splitting on a regex would do it.

```
f = File.new("some_file.csv")
res = f.readlines.map{|line| line.chomp.split(/[\t,]/)}
f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Brutal solution:

```
require 'csv'
csv= CSV.new("some_file")
csv.instance_variable_set(:@col_sep, /[\t,]/)
```